# Whoami: cannot find name for user id 0

Tags: linux, users

When I run `whoami` it says:

> whoami: cannot find name for user id 0

My `/etc/passwd` file looks like this:

```
root::0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Your /etc/passwd is broken? Can you post the contents

Comment: What's your `id command` in `current shell` when you get whoami?.

Comment: (1) Which linux distribution? (2) What is output of `pwck` and `grpck`? (3) Does file `/etc/shadow` exist?

Comment: If you have `ltrace` installed, try `ltrace whoami`. You should see a call to `getpwuid()` there.

Comment: Also, have you set up (or attempted to) directory services of some sort (LDAP, NIS, etc.)? Have you touched `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?

Comment: I'm thinking `nsswitch.conf` as derobert mentioned. But I have seen `nscd` cause weird crap like this before. If it's running, try stopping it. If it is not running, try starting it (though the starting it if it's not running thing was an old RHEL bug that should not around any more).

Comment: The password hash entry should be 'x', i e. the line should be like `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash` (or similar). Would you mind posting `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?

Answer (score 9):

just say my experience
// after check /etc/passwd, /etc/shadow

### 0. problem

on broken device:

```
cat /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

and

```
whoami
whoami: cannot find name for user ID 0
```

on normal device:

```
whoami
root
```

### 1. research

try to find the reason:

```
strace whoami 2>&1 | grep -E '/etc|/lib'
...
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libnss_compat.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libnss_nis.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

found it need those *.so:

```
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libnss_compat.so.2
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libnsl.so.1
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libnss_nis.so.2
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libnss_files.so.2
```

//all come from `libc6` package, i work with arm linux device.

### 2. solution

i copy them to the broken device, then `whoami` worked right,

and bash prompt `I have no name!@localhost` got fixed.

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend checking the permissions on `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`. If they're not set to 644 (`-rw-r--r--`), then run:

`chmod 644 /etc/passwd; chmod 644 /etc/group`

Comment: still says cannot find name for user id 0

Answer (score 7):

Notice there is a missing `x`

This is the content of mine on Linux Mint with kernel 3.8.0-35-generic

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/zsh
```

The `x` means that the actual password information is being stored in a separate shadow password file, tipically `/etc/shadow`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd

Answer (score 1):

Check that each and every line in `/etc/passwd` has exactly seven fields.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's right on time, but the reason could be `coreutils` compiled without ACL support. Check it and rebuild the package if needed.